# Attach image browse button truncated

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

When attaching an image to a question/answer using the image upload tool, the ellipsis in the Browse button is cut off.

[image]

The button has a width of 7.0em. If you remove the width it should look correct. Or you could remove the ellipsis if you didn't actually want it to be shown. In Firefox, you see the first period of the ellipsis, which looks rather like a dead pixel (shown above). In Chrome, the ellipsis is cut off entirely.

Comment: IE8 also cuts off the ellipsis completely, for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put in a fix for this, will be in the next deployment. thanks.